# Accept default git commit message after a squashed merge

Tags: git, merge, commit, squash

I would like to do the following in a script:

```
git merge --squash someBranch
git push
```

The problem is that the merge does not do a commit. So before the push I have to commit. The default commit message created by this merge is sufficient. So my questions are:

1. Can I do the merge with automatically generating the commit?
2. Or can I add a command in the script to do a commit which accepts the default message?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask why you think the default is sufficient? Isn't the only reason for making a squash, that you want to make a bunch of commits from a branch appear as one commit? If the original commit messages make sense, they probably describe the original commits. In that case you probably want to rebase these commits in stead of squashing.

Comment: After 5 years I can't remember the reason for doing this ..

Comment: Hehe, understandable. Thanks for answering anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default commit message after a merge is in `.git/MERGE_MSG`, so you could do the following:

```
 git commit -F .git/MERGE_MSG
```

... after the merge.

Comment: Thanks! But in my special case I had to use `.git/SQUASH_MSG`.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like in more modern versions of git, you can try using the `--no-edit` option as described in the [git-merge docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) and in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897942/preventing-git-merge-from-confirming-commit-message).

```
git merge --no-edit --squash someBranch
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
git merge --squash someBranch
git commit -m ""
```

The `--no-edit` option doesn't work for me (Git 2.7.0). It says: `Squash commit -- not updating HEAD`.